# how to create plsql table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
begin
create or replace table ins_company_master
(
ins_company_id          NUMBER(2),    
ins_Company_code        VARCHAR(15),   
ins_company_name        VARCHAR(15),
ins_company_contact         VARCHAR(15),
ins_company_address         VARCHAR(15),
ins_company_location        VARCHAR(15),
ins_company_status          CHAR(1),
constraint ins_company_id   primary key(id),
constraint ins_company_code     unique(code)
); 
end;
/
```

Comment: express what you want explicitly please. Only code is not enough to express.

Comment: You can't use DDL in PL/SQL - you would need dynamic SQL for that. But why use PL/SQL to create a table to begin with? Plus: there is no `create or replace` for tables in Oracle.

Comment: Something like this... `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('Create table ....')`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it is *dynamic SQL* you need. Though, think twice! In Oracle, we - usually - don't create tables dynamically. We create them once, at SQL level, and use anywhere we want. That stands for *temporary tables* as well.

So, in your case, it would be as follows (note comments I wrote for lines 12, 13 and 14). Also, Oracle recommends us to use `VARCHAR2` datatype (not `VARCHAR`).

```
SQL> begin
  2  execute immediate '
  3  create table ins_company_master
  4  (
  5  ins_company_id          NUMBER(2),
  6  ins_Company_code        VARCHAR2(15),
  7  ins_company_name        VARCHAR2(15),
  8  ins_company_contact     VARCHAR2(15),
  9  ins_company_address     VARCHAR2(15),
 10  ins_company_location    VARCHAR2(15),
 11  ins_company_status      CHAR(1),
 12  constraint ins_company_id       primary key(ins_company_id),  --> fix column ...
 13  constraint ins_company_code     unique(ins_company_code)      --> ... names
 14  ) ';  --> remove semi-colon at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from ins_company_master;

no rows selected

SQL>
```